# SWFObject + x64 Flash Player 11

Tags: flash, swfobject

I have website that use SWFObject to load flash animation (http://www.michaeltomes.cz/)

I have installed Flash player 11 x64 and SWFObject now can't detect that I have Flash Player and shows me the version for non-flash users

Does anyone know about this problem? Any solution? Thanks

Comment: I've got a similar symptom on IE9 - still checking out other browsers. Any pointers to help track this down would be a great help!

Comment: Still haven't found any working solution...

Comment: I have one machine running IE9 that works and one that fails. It'll take some time on Monday to seek the cause...